# Python navigating nested dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I have a nested dictionary that might have non-unique keys

I need to dynamically add/get key-value pairs on this dictionary by their key in string format

The string that is the key name is being read from keyboard input in string format

Given that string I have to find a key that matches it and do something with a corresponding key-value pair

The keys might be non-unique among different nesting levels

But they are unique on a single nesting level

For example, I have this dict:

```
MyDict = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
```

Now, I get some input in string format that tells me to add one more nesting level with key 'c' and then fill it with a key-value pair 'a:3'. I do it like that:

```
last_edited_element = {'a': 3}
MyDict['c'] = last_edited_element
    
#MyDict is now {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': {'a': 3}}
```

Then, I get an input that tells me to do something with a key-value pair that has 'a' key

I am given a rule that first I have to look up for 'a' key in a level that was edited last, then If nothing is found - go one level up. I store my last edited element in a variable last_edited_element.

The last edited element was {'a': 3}, so I do:

```
if 'a' in last_edited_element:
     #do something with {'a': 3}
else:
     #go one level up and look for 'a' key there
```

So the question is, how do I go one level up? I have {a: '3'} stored in a variable last_edited_element, I need to access the upper-level dictionary if any that contains last_edited_element, something like last_edited_element.get_parent_dictionary()
How do I do that?

Comment: You could associate each nested level with its key in the parent dictionary

Comment: Is it a requirement that you do a bottom-up search? It's ideal to go top-down and then select the key you want

Comment: the input I am given forces me to search bottom-up, because I have to start search from the level that was last made changes to

Answer (score 0):

So following up on my first comment, you could do this:

1. Initialize a top-level dict
2. Initialize all children to refer to their parent
3. Recursively search bottom-up until you find a key or `None`

```
example_dict = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'parent': None}
example_dict['c'] = {'a': 3, 'parent': example_dict}

def find_key(k, d):
    if k in d:
        return d[k]
    elif d['parent'] is None:
        return None
    return find_key(k, d['parent'])
```

```
print(find_key('a', example_dict['c']))
> 3

print(find_key('b', example_dict['c']))
> 2
```

Comment: example_dict = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'parent': None}   
example_dict['c'] = {'a': 3, 'parent': example_dict}   this will result in recursion and will create a following dictionary: {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'parent': None, 'c': {'a': 3, 'parent': {...}}}

Comment: What do you mean @prupru?

Comment: @prupru the proposed solution searches bottom up from a specified node, but the data structure must be initialized to always provide a pointer to the parent, as there is no way to get the parent of the dictionary unless you explicitly encode this.

Comment: theese two lines example_dict = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'parent': None} example_dict['c'] = {'a': 3, 'parent': example_dict}, they do create a dictionary {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'parent': None, 'c': {'a': 3, 'parent': {...}}} what do those dots '...' mean? more nested dictionaries?

Comment: Yes they do. Although I do not see the problem.

Comment: but that creates an infinite dictionary that contains itself infinite times or not?

Comment: @prupru Oh okay! I see, I see! The `{...}` you are seeing is just `print` hiding the nested object, It's probably because it has strictly already showed it to you. Although you can show that as well, I'm sure, if you need to

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227996/discussion-between-kluvin-and-prupru).